# No puedo mostrar una imagen en Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Necesito mostrar la imagen de mi logo para mi portfolio pero ya intenté de todo y no me carga la imagen, aclaro que la imagen es un ".png" con el fondo transparente. El error que me aparece en el servidor es el siguiente:

"The requested resource isn't a valid image for /public/portfolio-logo.png received text/html; charset=utf-8"

Acá les dejo mi código:

```
import Navigation from "./Navigation"
import Image from "next/image"

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <header className="w-full h-12 font-medium text-2xl flex">
        <nav className="flex justify-between w-4/5 m-auto">
            <Image
                src={"/public/portfolio-logo.png"}
                width={100} 
                height={100} 
                alt="Portfolio Logo"
                priority={50}
                >
            </Image>
            <Navigation />
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: y si quitas el "/public"? si no mal recuerdo si pones `src="/portfolio-logo.png"` Next.js da por hecho que tu imagen esta en la carpeta "public"

Comment: Tal como comenta @Isaac, efectivamente Next.js interpreta las rutas según el enrutador de la aplicación. Todos los recursos en la carpeta `public` serán públicos y serán accesibles a través de la ruta raíz (`/`) de la aplicación.

Puedes revisar la [documentación específica](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#src) también.